# ng-if not working - Angular 1

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

Bit stuck... I have two inputs/repeat of radio buttons.

This code loops through an object data array and returns a drink name and price.  Eg, name: 'Tea', price: '1.00'.

```
<div class="field">
 <label class="radio" ng-repeat="drink in grindsIndex.menuDrinks" >
  <input id='drinkRadio' type="radio" ng-model="value" value="{{ 
   drink.price }}" placeholder="{{ drink.name }}" name="name" ng-
   model="grindsIndex.name" ng-change="drinkValue(value)" ng-
   click="clickMethod()"; [checked]="idx === 0" ng-class="{selected: 
   drink.selected === true}"/>
    {{ drink.name }}  &nbsp
    {{ drink.price }}
 </label>
</div>
```

When someone clicks on the radio button 'Tea', I want this set of radio buttons to appear...  But the NG-IF doesn't seem to work.

```
    <div class="field" ng-if="drink.name == 'tea'">
    <label class="radio" ng-repeat="drink in grindsIndex.menuDrinks" >
    <input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="{{ drink.price }}" placeholder="{{ drink.select }}" name="select" ng-model="grindsIndex.name" ng-change="drinkValue(value)" ng-click="clickMethod()"/>
    {{ drink.select }}  &nbsp
    {{ drink.price }}

    </label>
  </div>
```

Basically I want to say, if drink.name === 'tea', show these radio buttons...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is because drink.name inside ng-if="drink.name == 'tea'" is undefined since it is outside the scope of ng-repeat. What you can do is to use ng-model of your first input ng-model="value" as

```
ng-if="value.name == 'tea'"
```

or you can create a new variable and set it to true when your condition is met on ng-click or ng-change of first input.

```
<div class="field" ng-if="displayTea">
</div>
```

and in your controller set this new variable true when condition is met

```
$scope.clickMethod = function(){
    if(someConditionIsMet)
        displayTea = true;
}
```